# getting values from sql and put them on checkboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, checkbox, checkboxlist

I need to get values from SQL Server and put the values to checkboxes. For example

I have table cities on sql  using form ı will add city names to database later on ı want to get such city names and put them on `checkboxes`. When I add new city to table cities additional `checkbox` will be created `dynamically` and new city name will be put there

Comment: @HariPrasad I can easily add cities to table but ı am not sure how ı need to proceed with creating dynamic checkboxes ı am stucked at creating new checkboxes and put saved values to them

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
((ListBox)MyCheckBoxList).DataSource = dt; // datatable containg cities
((ListBox)MyCheckBoxList).DisplayMember = "cityname";
((ListBox)MyCheckBoxList).ValueMember = "id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CheckboxList** control of ASP.NET, and bind the city column to that control.

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [City] FROM [tblCities]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
       
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="city" DataValueField="City">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```